# SQL Insert data in first available row id

Tags: sql, insert

I have a SQL table that has a primary key (`Row_id`) that has a format like:

```
110001  
110002  
110003  
...
```

This table may be updated by removing some rows over time. I have a php script and want to have it insert new rows to first available position not just to increase the last existing id.

for example if I have this:

```
110001  
110002  
110004  
110005
```

I want to new row be inserted and given the `id = 110003` not `110006`.

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is a terrible idea.  Don't do it.

Comment: please, check my working answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know why you want to reuse id(s) but, here we go

Suppose that you're table name is `Tbl`:

```
Select MIN(a.Id + 1)
From   Tbl A 
       Left Join Tbl B
         On A.Id = B.Id - 1
Where  B.Id Is NULL
```

this should works for retrieve the id that you want. 
After that, obviously, you have to do an insert based on the previous value.
So

```
INSERT into yourTable(id,....) VALUES(
    Select MIN(a.Id + 1)
    From   Tbl A 
           Left Join Tbl B
             On A.Id = B.Id - 1
    Where  B.Id Is NULL,
    .....)
```

[image]

Comment: what if I wanted the Tbl itself be result of another select? would you please provide me with the query?

Comment: @bijibuji i can't understand your question. Try to be more accurate, please.

Comment: I dont already have the exact table Tbl, but it is the result of another SELECT. how can I embed that SELECT in your suggested query?

Comment: @bijibuji Take a look at the second query that I have written above, and use that as the base for your next query

Comment: Thanks! it is working fine now. please let me ask you two more questions Don, ... how can I access the resulting product_id in php, as it is listed under 'MIN(a.product_id + 1)' field when I run the query in phpmyadmin. I want to use the resulting product_id (like 110001) in php

Comment: @bijibuji it will `min` but you can alias it, like i've done with table in my query. Method is the same

Comment: please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267623/after-aliasing-sql-field-on-select-i-can-not-access-the-result-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your id a UNIQUE one
Then run a for/while loop starting from 110001.

```
`$query = "...";
try {
    mysql_query($query);
} catch(Exception $ex) {
    if (mysql_errno() == 1062) {
        throw new Exception('The email you used exists already');
    } else {
        throw $ex;
    }
}
```

`
The 1062 error is raised whenever a unique key is broken. We need to catch it because of the unique email field, but it could also be raised because you broke the primary key or another unique field that we ignore the existence. You will have to adapt this code in case you think some other unique constraints might break as well during this query.

If the query succeeds; you can insert that particular id.